# Gray triangles left inside my wall

Tags: texturing, modifiers

as you can guess I'm very new to Blender and I have a problem. I used the boolean process to create holes in my wall and then applied the process. As soon as I did though, triangles such as this appeared. I tried filling (Edit mode-select edge-alt+f) but it did literally nothing. I also tried cutting (Edit mode-Select edge-K) but it didn't work also. I'm very much stuck at this point and need professional help (not for my mental health atm). Care to lend a hand, please?[image]

Comment: Is it a hole, or texture is missing?

Comment: Missing texture. :(

Comment: I suppose is a UV problem. Try selecting face and pressing [U] ⇾ unwrap to see if it helps

Comment: Holy s-! That did the trick alright. Thanks so much, bruv, I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Crantisz, for the comment, it was the answer.

To explain, there was A UV problem, which made the texture disappear.

I selected the faces and pressed `U` > `Unwrap` to solve the problem.